# html background color issue

Tags: html

I have a background color of #efefef (greyish), color loads just fine in every browser.

Problem is that when I copy the whole file from the browser and paste it in an e-mail, then the background color changes to white.

How do I keep it the same color?

```
<body bgcolor="#efefef" link="#ff6633" alink="#ff6633" vlink="#ff6633">
```

Comment: Does your email support HTML? Usually if it supports it works fine.

Comment: yes, the rest of the document loads perfect, its just the background color

Comment: some one told me about the bg style I can use, do you know how to implement that correctly?

Comment: so link alink vlink colors work?

Comment: Does only the background color go missing, or also the link colors? Are you sure the `<body>` tag makes it into the email? Otherwise you may want to wrap the whole content in a div with a style attribute.

Comment: yes it does, just the bgcolor in the email

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div style="background-color:#EFEFEF">
<p>EMAIL TEXT</p>
</div>
```

in your email.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `<body>` tags in html email. All email clients will strip out any `<body>` `<head>` tags etc.

You need to rebuild the email using `tables` and use inline styles to style the elements.

HTML emails are notoriously difficult to code. The way you are trying to do it simply will not work i'm afraid.

Here is a brief introduction to coding html email: http://www.sitepoint.com/code-html-email-newsletters/

Comment: no i'm not coding in the email section, read my problem again, i'm just pasting my entire site in an email, but only the background color goes missing, everything else is fine

Comment: The background is disappearing because, as I said, the email client will strip out the body tag